# Why loop() in Looper class gets called multiple times

Tags: android, debugging, android-handler, android-looper

I have a simple piece of code which starts an intent but when I debug it passes through various classes and often makes me wonder why these classes get called every time and what tasks are they performing before coming back to normal execution.

[image]

the control of execution then shifts to **View** class and calls `performClick()`
[image]

after then it goes to **Handler** class and calls `dispatchMessage(Message msg)`
[image]
and at last, it calls `loop()` of **Looper** class a number of times before coming back to normal flow.
[image]
so can someone help me here understand what is happening under the hood and why this loop() gets called multiple times?

Comment: see `android/app/ActivityThread.java` source file

Comment: not everyone knows handler looper or how multithreading works in Android  behind the scenes and questions related this should not be downvoted in any sense unless it's not valid, at least add your review if someone downvotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `loop()` is part of the `Looper` class. Deep in your android app when your process initializes the application, the first thing the JVM looks for is an entry point, which in all Java applications is the main method. The android main method exists in  a class called `ActivityThread` (check the [AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java) for the activity thread).

The beauty of this class is that it does a few things,

1. The Looper in the `ActivityThread`'s main method calls the `prepareMainLooper()` method. This. initializes the current thread as the application's main looper. i.e this is where your main thread receives its **mainthread** designation, that differs it from all other threads at runtime.
2. Also in the main method, a handler is responsible for managing a [MessageQueue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/MessageQueue.html) where messages from your app are received and handled. It is important to note a [Messages] can be executed by the MessageQueue as a Runnable or other executable object.

What makes android different than most desktop/console like java applications is the [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) class. This class has a `Looper.loop()` method that is called within the `ActivityThread`'s main method, and it runs an infinite loop thanks to a `for(;;){}` (the double semicolon indicates infinite loop). This loop will continue to run indefinitely as unless the `quit()` is called externally. The loop method calls `message.next()` each time it has completed with a message, to retrieve a new message.

In short, without this infinite looping method, it would be difficult for android to have a basic way to process incoming messages asynchronously, which is at the core of Android's event driven nature. The loop is eagerly seeking new messages to process or pass to the handler.

Checkout the [AOSP](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java) for a deeper dive if you're interested!